# Is My jQuery Plugin Template Faulty

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i fetched a jQuery template and did some trimming. But on init function -as you can see- on line 46, element's CSS should be changed. But nothing happens. Here is my plugin code; http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7gQ9jS03

Thanks in advance.

Edit: index.js of the page is;

```
$(function() {

    $("#asd").Loading();

});
```

and the html is;

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<div id="asd"></div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are there any console log errors? Also, i believe, it should be `$(this.element).css('background-color': '#f00')`

Comment: please show the code you are using to invoke the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `$(this.element)`.